# Carriagereturn(CR) to LF+CR

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

i want to convert CR to CR+LF in batch file.
Howe can i do this by writing batch file.
Please help.

I am taking input from file and in that file i want to change CR to CR+LF

Comment: This is essentially the same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110031/batch-file-convert-lf-to-crlf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the good old unix command awk:

```
awk 'sub("$", "\r")' unix.txt > win.txt
```

Comment: We have a shell script file named LineFeed.sh which does a function of convertinf a Linefeed(LF) to Carriage Return + LineFeed.  We want the same to be done by a batch file in windows . Is it possible.

Regards,
SureshDharmdaurai

Comment: @sureshdharmadurai: it is certainly possible but I doubt it will be possible with the *standard* available dos commands.

Comment: @Lieven: not in DOS but in Windows batch files easily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110031/batch-file-convert-lf-to-crlf/3112785#3112785