# Carriage return + Linefeed => Line feed

Tags: windows, macos, terminal

I understand that Mac OS X uses Unix convention of a new line, Windows uses carriage return, linefeed at the end of lines.

Do you know any tools to convert Carriage return + Linefeed to  Line feed working on mac os? or Any commands to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Mac you could use something such as dos2unix and unix2dos (http://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/).
If you are creating files on Windows and moving them to a mac you can use a program like notepad and change the EOL setting ([EOL conversion in notepad ++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239551/eol-conversion-in-notepad)).

Indiana University has a good page on this at https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux, which if you use the perl method and a scripting language to convert many files at once.  You could even use automator on the mac to create a droplet where you drop one or more text files onto it and it automatically converts the file.