# ksh syntax error: `if' unmatched

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, ksh

I'm new in ksh world and I have a problem right now with a script. The script under this lines is into the .profile file of a user in a UNIX machine and when I try to connect whith him i get always the error

> home/userTest/.profile: syntax error: `if' unmatched

I don't know how to solve this, because I suppose that this scripts defines the prompt for the connected user, and if I have this error the prompt only shows "$"

I tried the command

> ksh -n /home/userTest/.profile

and I get the error always in the last line of the file

```
#!/bin/ksh
# ksh example 
if [[$0 = "ksh"]];
then
  bash
  exit $?
fi

if [[$0 = "-ksh"]];
then
  bash --login
  exit $?
fi

export LOGIN=$LOGNAME

#prompt config
PS1="$LOGIN@"$(hostname)":$PWD"

if [["$(id -u)" = "0"]];
then
  export PS1="$PS1# "
else
  export PS1="$PS1> "
fi

#Alias utile
alias ll="ls -la"

#Set any export here
export PATH_EXAMPLE=/home/userTest
export JAVA_HOME=$PATH_EXAMPLE/games/java/current
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: I did not received any error when I have copied you code as it is and run a check with "ksh -n" .
which ksh you are using ksh88 or ksh93

Comment: If a use the ksh --version command i get "version         sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-06-21", so I guess that i have ksh93

Comment: There's no need to check if the user is running as root.  Put `\$` in PS1, and it will be rendered as $ or # depending on whether or not the user is root.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error. Turned out it was due to DOS format newlines (CRLF) in my *.sh file created in Windows and then transferred to a Linux server.

## Commands to convert DOS format newlines (CRLF) to UNIX format newlines (LF)

- In Windows: using Notepad++, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239551/eol-conversion-in-notepad/16244079#16244079):

> - Select "Edit" > "EOL Conversion" > "UNIX/OSX Format".
> - You can also set the default EOL in notepad++ via "Settings" -> "Preferences" -> "New Document/Default Directory" then select "Unix/OSX" under the Format box.

- In UNIX/Linux: using one of the techniques explained [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/):

> - Convert DOS to UNIX using `sed` command:
>
> ```bash
> sed 's/^M$//' input.txt > output.txt
> ```
>
> - Convert DOS to UNIX using `tr` command:
>
> ```bash
> tr -d '\r' < input.txt > output.txt
> ```
>
> - Convert DOS to UNIX using this Perl one-liner:
>
> ```bash
> perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' input.txt
> ```
>
> - Convert DOS to UNIX using `dos2unix` command:
>
> ```bash
> dos2unix input.txt
>
> # or, with a backup:
> dos2unix -b input.txt
> ```

## [ Bonus tip ] Commands to convert UNIX format newlines (LF) to DOS format newlines (CRLF)

- Convert UNIX to DOS using `unix2dos` command:

```bash
unix2dos input.txt

# or, with a backup:
unix2dos -b input.txt
```

- Convert UNIX to DOS using `sed` command:

```bash
sed 's/$/\r/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using following version

```
version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
```

I did not received any syntax error for your above code , though there a problem with your if statement condition instead of

```
if [[$0 = "-ksh"]]
```

it should be

```
 if [[ $0 == "-ksh" ]]
```

or

```
if [[ $0 = "-ksh" ]]
```

the latter is obsolete

The complete code is as below

```
#!/bin/ksh
# ksh example
if [[ $0 = "ksh" ]];
then
  bash
exit $?
fi

if [[ $0 == "-ksh" ]];
then
   bash --login
   exit $?
fi

export LOGIN=$LOGNAME

#prompt config
PS1="$LOGIN@"$(hostname)":$PWD"

if [[ "$(id -u)" == "0" ]];
then
export PS1="$PS1# "
else
   export PS1="$PS1> "
fi

#Alias utile
alias ll="ls -la"

#Set any export here
export PATH_EXAMPLE=/home/userTest
export JAVA_HOME=$PATH_EXAMPLE/games/java/current
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

You script may be having some unwanted character , try to look out for then using `cat -vte`
you can also try command `dos2unix filename` and then run `ksh -n`

Comment: I finally I get my problem solved. I was creating mi .ksh file from windows, and then uploading it to my unix machine. When I create the file from unix the problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: if you had run dos2unix filename ... that would have solved your problem .... it replaces the ctrl M character with unix line end.