# Double slash // comments in my php wordpress theme are breaking my site

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok, maybe I'm missing something, but I am modifying a wordpress theme functions.php file.

I am adding comments in the form of

```
 add_shortcode( 'member', 'member_check_shortcode' );

 function member_check_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

 if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() ) { 

# THIS IS A COMMENT

    $content = "logged in as " . $username1;

    return $content;
 }
return '';
}
```

This breaks the site and I get the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/politehr/public_html/wp-content/themes/politehr/functions.php on line 558

Same code with the comment removed:

```
 add_shortcode( 'member', 'member_check_shortcode' );

 function member_check_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

 if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() ) { 

    $content = "logged in as " . $username1;

    return $content;
 }
return '';
}
```

This does not break the site.

Same problem using double slashes: //

Same problem if I add ?> to the bottom of the file (it's not there on the 2013 theme). (edit: what I meant to say is that the problem is not solved by adding ?> to the bottom of the file)

What causes this problem?

EDIT: responding to comment:

@Ben comments in the format of /* comment */ work ok.

This site is brand new and I have no plugins activated.

It is the Twenty Thirteen theme that is standard with WP.

UPDATE:

Everyone who says that the code is somehow being minified or line breaks removed are probably correct...anyone know how to fix that and make my notepad++ editor insert line breaks? Or is WP doing this? I'm using notepad++ and then uploading via filezilla.

SOLUTION:

[EOL conversion in notepad ++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239551/eol-conversion-in-notepad)

Comment: Very interesting. Just out of curiosity, does it work if you have comments in the /* format? eg: `/* This is my comment */`

Comment: do you have a plugin on the site that has a documentor?  I would susect it is reading that line as a broken annotation command.

Comment: my guess minification?, the ?> closing php tags are not required, and in fact personally I don't ever use them.  Are you adding this code through an wordpress editor, or in the file itself?

Comment: Can you post the link of wp theme?

Comment: OK. I agree with @ArtisiticPhoenix - the fact that `/* comment */` works and anything that 'comments out' the rest of the line (# and //) doesn't implies that somehow the file is being either minified, or your interpreter might be expecting different line endings (UNIX vs Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time ago, something like that happens to me. The reason was the differents EOL characters between platforms (Windows and Linux, in my case).
The code I edited locally was transformed into one single line of code when uploaded, and the `//` comments breaks the code after them.

Comment: I believe this may the answer as the errors always appear to be "line 30" even though my Notepad++ shows a different line number. Now, how do I fix this?

Comment: My problem was the files were created on Linux and then edited on Windows, I resolved it creating a new fresh file on Windows and pasting the code on it. Weird, but worked for me.

Comment: Also, if you can edit the file directly on the server (via cPanel, or FTP), you can try adding the missings EOLs.

Comment: It's the theme functions file so it's large. I will attempt to fix and post how I do it.  Pasting into notepad and then back to notepad++ did not work.

Comment: It was notepad++ - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239551/eol-conversion-in-notepad. I marked this as the answer.

Comment: Great! I use Notepad++ occasionally (I always work with Netbeans), now I will pay attention to this, just in case...