# Shell script is not running in ubuntu

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu, libx265

I have the following script in a bash script `encode.sh`.

```
echo "1 configuration out of 936"
x265 incident_10d_384x288_25.yuv --input-res 384x288 --fps 25 str/incident_10d_384x288_25_QP_0_ON_B0.bin --tune psnr --psnr --preset medium --max-merge 5 --merange 64 --no-open-gop -I 48 -i 8 --tu-intra-depth 3 --tu-inter-depth 3 --input-depth 8 --aq-mode 0 --b-adapt 0 --scenecut 48 --ref 4 --sao --deblock=0:0 --bframes 0 --qp 0 --csv-log-level 2 --log-level 4 --csv csv/incident_10d_384x288_25_QP_0_ON_B0.csv > txt/1_incident_10d_384x288_25_QP_0_ON_B0.txt 2<&1 
echo "2 configuration out of 936"
x265 incident_10d_384x288_25.yuv --input-res 384x288 --fps 25 str/incident_10d_384x288_25_QP_1_ON_B0.bin --tune psnr --psnr --preset medium --max-merge 5 --merange 64 --no-open-gop -I 48 -i 8 --tu-intra-depth 3 --tu-inter-depth 3 --input-depth 8 --aq-mode 0 --b-adapt 0 --scenecut 48 --ref 4 --sao --deblock=0:0 --bframes 0 --qp 1 --csv-log-level 2 --log-level 4 --csv csv/incident_10d_384x288_25_QP_1_ON_B0.csv > txt/2_incident_10d_384x288_25_QP_1_ON_B0.txt 2<&1 
echo "3 configuration out of 936"
x265 incident_10d_384x288_25.yuv --input-res 384x288 --fps 25 str/incident_10d_384x288_25_QP_2_ON_B0.bin --tune psnr --psnr --preset medium --max-merge 5 --merange 64 --no-open-gop -I 48 -i 8 --tu-intra-depth 3 --tu-inter-depth 3 --input-depth 8 --aq-mode 0 --b-adapt 0 --scenecut 48 --ref 4 --sao --deblock=0:0 --bframes 0 --qp 2 --csv-log-level 2 --log-level 4 --csv csv/incident_10d_384x288_25_QP_2_ON_B0.csv > txt/3_incident_10d_384x288_25_QP_2_ON_B0.txt 2<&1
```

I want to write the output of each encoding from terminal to a txt file using `> txt/3_incident_10d_384x288_25_QP_2_ON_B0.txt 2<&1`. I create the bash script from `windows` using `python 2.7` and I want to run it in `ubuntu`.

When I copy a line from bash script and run it in terminal it's working. But when I want to run it from batch file it's not working.

I get no error in terminal but the `x265` encoder does not run with a warning:

```
[warning]: extra unused command arguments given <
```

Is there any special character in my shell script?

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I think you are looking for `2>&1`, to redirect standard error to the currently opened standard output.

Comment: what `2<&1`is supposed to do ? if you want to redirect stdout to stderr, that would be `1>&2`, or redirect stderr to stdout : `2>&1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output redirection uses `>&`, not `<&`. That would be

`2>&1` or `1>&2`

(probably the first one, redirect standard error (2) to standard output (1) )

related question on Stack Overflow : [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash)

---

EDIT:

Apparently, you also had the error message in the other order :

> [warning]: extra unused command arguments given >`

which is more surprising.

As per our small discussion in comments, **it was due to incorrect line endings** handling. Probably the whole script was seen as only one big line, which would explain that bash was surprised to see several redirections.

For information, in case comments get deleted : using Notepad++ menu `Edit > EOL Conversion` solved the issue. More info here : [EOL conversion in notepad ++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239551/eol-conversion-in-notepad)

Comment: Thank you! I also have to copy and paste the code in the shell file in `ubuntu` server and not just copy/paste it. May some special characters from windows are also a potential problem.

Comment: @zinon I am not sure to understand your comment. Is that another problem you have ? In this case I recommend to open a new question with specific details.

Comment: Your proposed solution works only if I open the bash script in windows, copy the content and past it in a bash script file in linux. In case I drag and drop the bash script file from windows to linux, the problem still remains.

Comment: @zinon The same problem exactly? With the message `[warning]: extra unused command arguments given <` ? I am not aware of encoding problem turning `>` into `<`, I would recommend double checking you saved your file before drag&dropping it .

Comment: Yes, the same warning but having `>` instead of `<`. I double check it. I have a feeling that `"\n"` new line character after `2>&1 ` might be the problem. In any case, thank you for your help!

Comment: Newlines could be a problem indeed. How do you save / generate your scirpt file exactly ? Any decent text editor should have a function for end-of-lines (EOL) conversions. "Decent" means lots of them but **not Notepad.exe** :))

Comment: You can try to play with line endings in the 'Edit > EOL conversion' menu to see if it solves your issue.

Comment: More info here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239551/eol-conversion-in-notepad

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I will try it!!

Comment: You are right! `Edit > EOL conversion` solve my problem!