# HTTP request using Bash

Tags: python, bash, shell, httprequest

I have a python code that will send a HTTP request to a webserver to update its time according to PC time and this code works fine:

```
current_time = str(time.time())
url = "http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/Operation.cgi?data={\"action\":\"synctime\",\"newtime\":" + current_time + "}"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Then I'm trying to translate this code into a bash script to do the same thing and this is what I have:

```
current_time=$(date +%s)
url="http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/Operation.cgi?data={\"action\":\"synctime\",\"newtime\":$current_time}"
response=$(curl -s "$url")
```

I'm echoing result from the URL variable and it looks like this:

```
}ttp://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/Operation.cgi?data={"action":"synctime","newtime":1681742302
```

There's a closing curly braces in the beginning of this string replacing the "h" letter and I don't understand why the output being like this.
I tried to change the format to use single quotes and also concatenate the current_time variable in url variable but nothing seems to work.

Can someone please explain why this curly braces is where it is and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Your file has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: @executable this is exactly what I did. Take a look at the code I published.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm using notepad++ to avoid this mistake. Would you recommend a different editor or something that I can use to remove dos line endings?

Comment: Notepad++ will not "protect" you against dos line endings, no editor will. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239551/eol-conversion-in-notepad

Comment: @KamilCuk you were right on target. Checked this topic about eol conversion and using Notepad++ > Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix (LF) did the job! Thank you very much for your help!