# Line Normalizing causes my site to break

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, master-pages, line-endings

I've got a rather strange problem. This morning when I started working on my project I got a PopUp in Visual Studios:

```
    The line endings in the following file are not consistent. Do you want to normalize the line endings?
```

I clicked Yes......and since then my project has started behaving strange. The Master Page is not Loading the CSS nor JavaScript nor JQuery nor even the Images from Images folder.

After checking in FireBug, I realized that the Files/Images are not loading from the specified path.

Is there a way to revert the Line Normalization back or an alternative so that the required files/images can be loaded from the specified path.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Windows 8.1

Any Help is appreciated....
Thanks :)

Comment: If you're using Source Control, just revert it using that. IF you're not using Source Control you should be using source control.

Comment: #George: I don't use Source Control or any other version control. Is there any other way revert back the Normalization.

Comment: You should be able to hit 'ctrl+z' if you haven't closed the Visual Studio window since this happened.  Also: Use Source Control.

Comment: Also, there's a way to do it detailed in this Stack Overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341660/change-eol-on-multiple-files-in-one-go You could do the same thing in Visual Studio.

Comment: a) cannot use 'ctrl+z' since I restarted VS after this problem occurred. b) As mentioned in the referenced Question, I tried replacing but that does not work aswell.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about how you went about 'replacing' and 'does not work'.

Comment: Tried replacing \n with \r\n. This replaces all occurrences of \n in my js file and jQuery plugin. This does not replace any thing with line normalization.

Comment: After almost 3 days of Relentless hard work and research, I found out that the a) the DTD of my Master Page had changed from `Inherits="ABC_XYZ.MasterPage"` to `Inherits="ABC_XYZ.DefaultPage" `, similarly the .cs file instead of Extending the MasterPage it was Extending the DefaultPage. b) Also since I was using a CustomControl for Playing Videos , I had to change the settings in the `web.config` file for the control. P.S: I don't know if this started occurring due to the Line Normalizing (it could be), but I am very happy and glad that my site is up and runnning... :)