# End of line character is invalid

Tags: php, command-line, command-prompt, phpcodesniffer

I checked my code using php codesniffer and got this error:

[image]

It says the error happened in the first line of the code, but all I have in the first line of my code is a php opening tag:

```
<?php
```

Is there a program to show these characters and fix it? I also tried phpcbf command but it doesn't appear to work:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using windows.
Your file uses unix lineendings ("\n")
Windows uses ("\r\n")

you could convert the lineendings in the commandline with

```
type input_filename | more /P > output_filename
```

or open your sourcefiles with an editor like notepad++ and change lineendings to windows

Comment: Thanks the command didn't work work for me, but notepadd++ did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341660/change-eol-on-multiple-files-in-one-go

Answer (score 0):

PHP codesniffer should be checking against the default EOL of the OS it is running on, so EOL will be \n for Linux and \r\n for Windows.

Most likely, what has happened is that one of the files you are checking has the wrong or mixed EOL for the current OS (this is what happened to me).  This might not be obvious as file editors often compensate for this.

Many editors, though, do have a feature to tell you what the EOL of the file is, or even to reset it.  Notepad++ on Windows has this from the Edit menu.  On linux, use the `file` command to detect, and use `dos2unix` or `unix2dos`, as needed.