# SSDT publish script recreates procedures with no changes

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, sqlproj

I have a database imported into a `.sqlproj`, and a `.publish.xml` publish profile which publishes changes to a remote DB.

My understanding is that when I right click -> Publish -> Generate Script, it should calculate the diff between the local definitions and the remote DB, and generate a script to bring the remote DB in line.

This all seems to work OK, however, the script it generates always contains `ALTER FUNCTION` and `ALTER PROCEDURE` statements for the same 40 or so functions and procedures (out of a total of around 1000 defined), *whether they have changed or not*. When I compare the `ALTER` statements with the Script Function as -> ALTER to script in SSMS, they are exactly the same.

So my question is: Why does VS think these are different, or why would it recreate them anyway if they are the same?

Notes:

- The functions are not special - some of them are as simple as defining a varchar, setting it to a value and returning it.
- I've tried running the `ALTER` scripts into the database, but they continue to be generated.
- I've checked the properties (right click -> properties) in SSMS but can't see anything obviously different about those it always recreates and those it does not.
- My publish profile is the bog standard one.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use "schema compare" in SSDT to see what it "thinks" the differences are? It's often helpful to do this, and then paste the "target" script into your source file; this way you can be sure you have the "canonical" form of the script. I've see this more often with constraints and trigger than with stored procedures, to be fair. Googling "SSDT canonical form" may help.

Comment: Smells like there are differences, but we cannot see them. are there tabs vs. spaces differences? Are the line endings in both versions CR, LF, or CR+LF? Ideally you would do a bit-wise comparison of the 2 versions, not just a visual one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

By renaming the .dacpac as a .zip and extracting the model.xml I could see the `<HeaderContents>` of some of the procedures had `&#xA;` (LF - the Line Feed character) in them.

This made me realise that for some reason all my .SQL files had unix line endings (LF) instead of windows line endings (CR LF). Converting all the files to window line endings ([using notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25109311/1225497)) solved the problem.

**Original:**

OK, it looks like most of them are due to string constants in the scripts containing new line characters. Replacing them with their manually defined characters means they're not longer picked up for redeployment.
i.e.

```
SET @doesnt_work = 
'FOO
BAR'
```

can be replaced with

```
SET @works = 'FOO'  + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'BAR'
```

Note: This is more of a workaround than a solution, and hopefully someone can suggest a better way to do this...

Comment: If I Create a database that contains _only_ the procedure
````
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spReturnsEmbeddedCR]

AS
 DECLARE @mystring varchar(100);
 Set @mystring = 'Some
     Text';
 SELECT @mystring;
RETURN 0
````
it doesn't get redeployed. Are the procs in question being generated somehow? Schema compare is quite sensitive to seemingly innocuous changes.

Comment: You're right, there's something more involved going on. I'm now attempting to use sqlpackage to deploy the changes, and it seems to vary depending on whether I deploy from my local machine or the TFS server. Both are windows machines - any idea why they would treat new lines differently?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and was able to resolve it by:

1. Changing my global Git configuration to use Windows line endings:
   `git config --global core.autocrlf true`.
2. Deleting the local repo and re-cloning it.