# SSDT & TFS: compare SQL Server database not working

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I have a database project with SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) in Visual Studio 2015 and TFS source control.

This morning while I was trying to compare two databases (DB -> TFS), it didn't work and I got an error:

> Comparison completed. Difference detected. Restricted comparison. See error list for detail

And in error list window warning was:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       The login for the target does not have the VIEW ANY
>   DEFINITION permission. The comparison will be restricted to database
>   scoped elements if the source is a database.

SQL Server user for SSDT was `sa`.

Thanks in advance

[image: ScreenShot]

---

**UPDATE:**
I fixed comparison warning by following query but main problem is exist yet:

```
USE [master]
GO

Grant VIEW ANY DEFINITION to [USERNAME];
GO

USE [DBNAME]
GO

GRANT CONNECT to [USERNAME]
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [USERNAME]
```

Comment: How are you comparing them? Via a build definition? A release definition? What command are you executing to compare them?

Comment: @DanielMann With Schema Compare Wizard

Comment: Then what does this have to do with TFS? It sounds like a Visual Studio or SSDT problem.

Comment: What is your question? The error message you posted seems clear enough.

Comment: @MartinSmith Please notice to picture, It's tell me about some difference but there is no change between source and target

Comment: @DanielMann Yes this is a problem or maybe I'm on wrong way. I want to know how can I fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem by drop and recreate object in MSSQLServer:

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997071/ssdt-publish-script-recreates-procedures-with-no-changes). Though you don't have string literals, it might still be working checking:

- What Schema Compare thinks the difference is - click the expand button to the left of 'Procedure'.
- If you have 'Ignore whitespace' turned on in the comparison options.
- If the line ending of your file are windows (`CR LF`) or unix (`LF`).
- (Brute force solution) Use `sqlpackage.exe` to extract the `.dacpac` of both databases, rename as `.zip`, and compare the contents of the two `model.xml`'s - there will be a difference in there somewhere.

Comment: I would also recommend checking the file encoding on both copies.

Comment: Dear @Taran your answer is so helpful, I'm working on this and found some new details. Please let me to check better