# Empty multi files Notepad++

Tags: emptydatatext

I have several types of files in the same folder.

How do I edit all files then `empty files`, then `save`, then `close all`, with one click in Notepad++ ?

Comment: I belive you can find answer on this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/11341759/1693815

Comment: thank you, really i try all but not work with my case.

Comment: what i want easy, just (open file, ctrl+a, del, save file), but with more than file it take time, i try micro but one file at time and manual, i want single click to empty 100 files. Thank you