# Windows command to convert Unix line endings?

Tags: windows, unix, batch-file, cmd, eol

Is there a Windows command to convert line endings of a file?

We have a `test.bat` which we need to run to start our server. We use Perforce and we need to have unix line endings in our workspace. For some reason, we are not allowed to change line endings to Windows in our workspaces. However, the server runs on Windows.

Everytime I have to run the bat file, I open it in Notepad++ and choose Edit→EOL conversion→Windows. Is there a way to automate this so that we won't need to manually change the line endings everytime we sync with Perforce?

Answer (score 73):

This can actually be done very easily using the `more` command which is included in Windows NT and later.  To convert `input_filename` which contains UNIX EOL (End Of Line) `\n` to `output_filename` which contains Windows EOL `\r\n`, just do this:

```
TYPE input_filename | MORE /P > output_filename
```

The `more` command has additional formatting options that you may not be aware of.  Run `more/?` to learn what else `more` can do.

Comment: this still works great in Windows 9, thanks! Might be worth mentioning that the file output_filename has to be existing before running this command and its content will be overwritten.

Comment: This seems to add an additional Newline to files that do not end with a newline, just a heads up if this matters for your particular scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately this also botches all the tabs to spaces.

Comment: I need the opposite of this. any idea?

Comment: Great answer! Slightly simpler: `more /P <input_file >output_file`

Comment: @Sebastian What's Windows 9?

Comment: @adrianTNT, you did `TYPE input_file | MORE /P > input_file`

Comment: @AndrewSteitz He wanted an in-place conversion.

Comment: @FranklinYu, you are correct. I was perplexed by your comment at first and then I realized that in my previous comment I forgot the "?" because I was asking (very poorly) if he actually typed that on the command line. Doh! I was asking (well, meant to ask) him because I was sure that it worked and even tried it to be 100% certain. Punctuation matters (and I goofed). I like the example "Can we eat, Grandma?" vs "Can we eat Grandma?" (1st, ask Grandma if we can eat. 2nd, asking  someone else if we can eat Grandma, LOL). Thank you for pointing out my mistake so I could clarify!!!

Answer (score 35):

Use [unix2dos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) utility. You can download binaries [here](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html).

Comment: Again its just an alternative to notepad++. Won't really get this automated. I will have to run this tool. I do change the line endings in notepad++ as of now.

Comment: It's a command line tool. And it's more suitable for automation, then GUI tools. You may write a periodical `at` job, which filters all files in some folder you put your batch files in. It all depends on what do you mean by automation.

Answer (score 21):

I was dealing with `CRLF` issues so I decided to build really simple tool for conversion (in NodeJS):

It's [NodeJS EOL converter CLI](https://github.com/jurosh/nodejs-eol-converter-cli)

So if you have **NodeJS with npm** installed you can try it:

```
npm i -g eol-converter-cli
eolConverter crlf "**/*.{txt,js,java,etc}"
```

Path might be configured dynamically by using Glob regex (same regex as in shell).

So if you can use NodeJS, it's really simple and you can integrate this command to convert whole workspace to desired line endings.

Comment: Looks like your solution hit https://www.reddit.com/r/programmingcirclejerk/comments/6t3kel/need_to_convert_unix_line_endings_in_windows_use/?ref=share&ref_source=link

Answer (score 16):

You can do this without additional tools in VBScript:

```
Do Until WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
  WScript.StdOut.WriteLine WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
Loop
```

Put the above lines in a file `unix2dos.vbs` and run it like this:

```
cscript //NoLogo unix2dos.vbs <C:\path\to\input.txt >C:\path\to\output.txt
```

or like this:

```
type C:\path\to\input.txt | cscript //NoLogo unix2dos.vbs >C:\path\to\output.txt
```

---

You can also do it in PowerShell:

```
(Get-Content "C:\path\to\input.txt") -replace "`n", "`r`n" |
  Set-Content "C:\path\to\output.txt"
```

which could be further simplified to this:

```
(Get-Content "C:\path\to\input.txt") | Set-Content "C:\path\to\output.txt"
```

The above statement works without an explicit replacement, because `Get-Content` implicitly splits input files at any kind of linebreak (CR, LF, and CR-LF), and `Set-Content` joins the input array with Windows linebreaks (CR-LF) before writing it to a file.

Comment: @FranklinYu With the PowerShell approach you can write the modified content back to the same file (the parentheses around `Get-Content` make that possible). As for "in-place" editing in general: [see here](http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/).

Comment: For that first powershell method with -replace, you would have to add the -raw option to get-content to do what you intend.  Just don't do it twice on the same file.  You don't even need to quote the filenames.  Note that using ">" or "out-file" in powershell 5 results in a "unicode" encoded file vs "ansi".

Answer (score 13):

Windows' MORE is not reliable, it destroys TABs inevitably and adds lines.

[unix2dos](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/) is part also of MinGW/MSYS, Cygutils, GnuWin32 and other unix binary port collections - and may already be installed.

When [python](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) is there, this one-liner converts any line endings to current platform - on any platform:

```bat
TYPE UNIXFILE.EXT | python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read())" > MYPLATFILE.EXT
```

or

```bat
python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write(open(sys.argv[1]).read())" UNIXFILE.EXT > MYPLATFILE.EXT
```

Or put the one-liner into a .bat / shell script and on the PATH according to your platform:

```bat
@REM This is any2here.bat
python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write(open(sys.argv[1]).read())" %1
```

and use that tool like

```bat
any2here UNIXFILE.EXT > MYPLATFILE.EXT
```

Answer (score 8):

Building on TampaHaze's and MD XF's helpful answers.

This will change all .txt files *in place* in the current directory from from LF to CRLF in Command Prompt

```
for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b "*.txt"') do ( type "%f" | more /p > "%f.1" & move "%f.1" "%f" )
```

If you don't want to verify every single change

> move

To

> move /y

To include subdirectories change

> dir /b

To

> dir /b /s

To do all this in a batch file including subdirectories without prompting for `.txt` files use below

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /b "*.txt"') do (
    type "%%f" | more /p > "%%f.1"
    move /y "%%f.1" "%%f" > nul
    @echo Changing LF-^>CRLF in File %%f
)
echo.
pause
```

Comment: Nope, this fails completely if there is a space in the filepath, such as, say, "C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\HTTPServer\conf\".

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
(for /f "delims=" %i in (file.unix) do @echo %i)>file.dos
```

Session protocol:

```
C:\TEST>xxd -g1 file.unix
0000000: 36 31 36 38 39 36 32 39 33 30 38 31 30 38 36 35  6168962930810865
0000010: 0a 34 38 36 38 39 37 34 36 33 32 36 31 38 31 39  .486897463261819
0000020: 37 0a 37 32 30 30 31 33 37 33 39 31 39 32 38 35  7.72001373919285
0000030: 34 37 0a 35 30 32 32 38 31 35 37 33 32 30 32 30  47.5022815732020
0000040: 35 32 34 0a                                      524.

C:\TEST>(for /f "delims=" %i in (file.unix) do @echo %i)>file.dos

C:\TEST>xxd -g1 file.dos
0000000: 36 31 36 38 39 36 32 39 33 30 38 31 30 38 36 35  6168962930810865
0000010: 0d 0a 34 38 36 38 39 37 34 36 33 32 36 31 38 31  ..48689746326181
0000020: 39 37 0d 0a 37 32 30 30 31 33 37 33 39 31 39 32  97..720013739192
0000030: 38 35 34 37 0d 0a 35 30 32 32 38 31 35 37 33 32  8547..5022815732
0000040: 30 32 30 35 32 34 0d 0a                          020524..
```

Comment: It works, but it also seems to remove all blank lines from the file. :(

Comment: @MarioVilas yes, you are right. You can use [flip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/) for this.

Answer (score 3):

My contribution for this, converting several files in a folder: 
`for %%z in (*.txt) do (for /f "delims=" %%i in (%%z) do @echo %%i)>%%z.tmp`

Answer (score 3):

If you have bash (e.g. git bash), you can use the following script to convert from unix2dos:

```sh
ex filename.ext <<EOF
:set fileformat=dos
:wq
EOF
```

similarly, to convert from dos2unix:

```sh
ex filename.ext <<EOF
:set fileformat=unix
:wq
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a simple batch script to do this for you:

```
TYPE %1 | MORE /P >%1.1
MOVE %1.1 %1
```

Then run `<batch script name> <FILE>` and `<FILE>` will be instantly converted to DOS line endings.

Answer (score 2):

I cloned my git project using the `git bash` on `windows`. All the files then had `LF` endings. Our repository has `CRLF` endings as default.

I deleted the project, and then cloned it again using the `Windows Command Prompt`. The `CRLF` endings were intact then. In my case, if I had changed the endings for the project, then it would've resulted in a huge commit and would've caused trouble for my teammates. So, did it this way. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: There is a way to use git to convert CRLF to LF i just used your approach to get LF ending, but i can not get it working. so i decided to change git configs here is a snippet:

$ git config --global core.autocrlf input

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple unix2dos.bat file that preserves blank lines and exclamation points:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%k in ('findstr /n "^" %1') do echo.%%l
```

The output goes to standard out, so redirect unix2dos.bat output to a file if so desired.

It avoids the pitfalls of other previously proposed for /f batch loop solutions by:
1) Working with delayed expansion off, to avoid eating up exclamation marks.
2) Using the for /f tokenizer itself to remove the line number from the `findstr /n` output lines.
   (Using findstr /n is necessary to also get blank lines: They would be dropped if for /f read directly from the input file.)

But, as Jeb pointed out in a comment below, the above solution has one drawback the others don't: It drops colons at the beginning of lines.

So 2020-04-06 update just for fun, here's another 1-liner based on findstr.exe, that seems to work fine without the above drawbacks:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=0123456789" %%l in ('findstr /n "^" %1') do echo%%l
```

The additional tricks are:
3) Use digits 0-9 as delimiters, so that `tokens=*` skips the initial line number.
4) Use the colon, inserted by `findstr /n` after the line number, as the token separator after the echo command.

I'll leave it to Jeb to explain if there are corner cases where `echo:something` might fail :-)
All I can say is that this last version successfully restored line endings on my huge [batch library](https://github.com/JFLarvoire/SysToolsLib/blob/master/Batch/Library.bat), so exceptions, if any, must be quite rare!

Comment: This drops all colons `:` from line beginnings. That destroys all batch functions. Btw. Test to convert a file with a line like `\..\..\windows\system32\calc.exe`. To solve this look at [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59879977/463115)

Comment: You're right!
I wanted to do a 1-liner, simpler and better than the previously published solutions, but apparently this cannot be done. Yours is the only correct so far.

Comment: But the challenge was irresistible, and maybe I have found another 1-line solution now, as shown in the edited text above :-)

Comment: And you failed again :-) Try it with `..\..\..\..\..\windows\system32\calc.exe`. The only **safe** ECHO form is the `echo(`. A one liner could be possible, but I suppose it's tricky

Comment: Caramba, schon wieder verpaßt!
OK, I give up for now. But I'm sure that one day, I'll make it!
:-)

Comment: Jeez, how many "ifs, ands, or buts" does Windows make things require? I can't follow any of this. I never thought the single most time consuming part of developing a whole custom PHP database view would be dealing with the line endings after copying the finished project to our server. Is there no Windows utility than can just fix this extremely common problem without all this headscratching?

Comment: UPDATE: Did it with Notepad++.

Comment: @John Smith: There are lots of ports of the unix2dos and dos2unix programs for Windows, which easily resolve the initial problem. See kxr's answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/35661818/2215591 for details.
Here, purely for the sake of the art, I was trying to do it using a short Windows batch script. This is very hard to do in that poor scripting language, if possible at all. But this very difficulty is why some of us find it a fun challenge. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Endoro's answer but to keep the blanks, try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" file.unix') do (
        set line=%%i
        set line=!line:*:=!
        echo(!line!
        ))>file.dos
```

Comment: Ir Relevant's solution works fine except it drop all exclamation mark (!).

Answer (score 1):

For convert UNIX(LF) to Windows(CR-LF) use next command on your windows terminal.

```
type file.txt > new_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but there is still **no correct answer using a `FOR /F` loop.**
(But you don't need a FOR loop at all, the [solution from @TampaHaze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27844521/463115) works too and is much simpler)

The [answer from @IR relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25206483/463115) has some drawbacks.
It drops the exclamation marks and can also drop carets.

```
@echo off
(
    setlocal Disabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%L in ('findstr /n "^" "%~1"') do (
        set "line=%%L"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:*:=!"
        (echo(!line!)
        endlocal
    )
) > file.dos
```

The trick is to use `findstr /n` to prefix each line with `<line number>:`, this avoids skipping of empty lines or lines beginning with `;`.
To remove the `<number>:` the `FOR "tokens=1,* delims=:"` option can't be used, because this would remove all leading colons in a line, too.

Therefore the line number is removed by `set "line=!line:*:=!"`, this requires EnableDelayedExpansion.
But with `EnableDelayedExpansion` the line `set "line=%%L"` would drop all exclamation marks and also carets (only when exclams are in the line).

That's why I disable the delayed expansion before and only enable it for the two lines, where it is required.

The `(echo(!line!)` looks strange, but has the advantage, that `echo(` can display any content in `!line!` and the outer parenthesis avoids accidentials whitespaces at the line end.

Answer (score 1):

To convert LF returns to CRLF without causing any tabs to spaces conversion using the `more` solution, try the `find /V` command, courtesy of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Conversion_between_newline_formats):

```
find /V "" < input_filename > output_filenam
```

Like the `more` answer, this does not do an in-place change.  But no external programs needed.  The `/V` says to output any input lines that do *not* match the pattern of an empty string, and nicely changes the line terminator to the Windows CRLF if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking an AWS course and have frequently had to copy from text boxes in the AWS web forms to Windows Notepad.  So I get the LF-delimited text only on my clipboard.  I accidentally discovered that pasting it into my Delphi editor, and then hitting Ctrl+K+W will write the text to a file with CR+LF delimiters.  (I'll bet many other IDE editors would do the same).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I really needed a short, simple, pure Windows solution. Lots of other answers, but I found FOR /F, MORE, FIND etc all failed in various ingenious ways and I didn't want to use an EXE, Python, VBS, Node, etc. And in these modern times the obvious answer has to be PowerShell. So here is my code.

```
ls <dir> | %{ (Get-Content $_.FullName) | Set-Content $_.FullName }
```

Simple huh? Works perfectly with one tiny proviso: it adds a CRLF to the end of the file if there wasn't one. For my purposes that was a bonus, not a problem!

Answer (score -2):

[Inserting Carriage Returns to a Text File](http://www.xpheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windowsxp-general/60533-inserting-carriage-returns-text-file.html)

```
@echo off
set SourceFile=%1 rem c:\test\test.txt
set TargetFile=%2 rem c:\test\out.txt

if exist "%TargetFile%" del "%TargetFile%"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%SourceFile%"') do call :Sub %%a
rem notepad "%TargetFile%"
goto :eof


:Sub
echo %1 >> "%TargetFile%"
if "%2"=="" goto :eof
shift
goto sub
```

Comment: Actually, it would work if he'd simply use something like `(for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%~1) do @echo.%%a)>"%~2"`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers   Yes, this `set TargetFile=%2 rem c:\test\out.txt` also needs improvement. And, btw, your `"tokens=*"` also.

Comment: @Endoro REM is a comment in a batch file, you can take out the %1 rem and then give it the specific file you need.  As I provided the link, I didn't feel I needed to further document as you were already working with a batch file, correct?  Please test it as it does work and it can be integrated into your existing batch files at will.  Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me in Windows 7.  I created a file c:\test\test.txt, with EOL from Unix, in Notepad++. Afterwards, I simply ran the batch file.  Again, it's not my code, it is code I slightly modified to not display Notepad?  I can show the OP how to make it work as opposed to that last comment.