# Can I replace Unix line endings with Windows line endings on the commandline?

Tags: windows, command-line, line-endings

I'm fiddling around with the `hg log` command to store the mercurial messages in a file, such as this (lines broken for readability):

```
hg log --template "Rev. {rev} from {date|rfc822date}:
    \r\n--------------------------------------------
    \r\n\t{desc|strip|fill68|tabindent}\r\n\r\n\r\n" > hglog.txt
```

The problem is with the `fill68` filter which breaks lines after 68 chars. In theory, that is, because those line breaks are Unix line breaks and are not displayed in Notepad.

Is there a way to replace `\n` with `\r\n`, by piping `hg log`'s output through another command maybe?

I wish to run this command in an automated VS post-build script, so I can't do this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Windows you can invoke the `MORE` command as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-eol-to-windows-eol):

```
hg log ... | more /p > hglog.txt
```

Comment: I have modified the solution

Comment: But note that this will fail if there is more than 65534 lines of text.