# Charset after FTP binary transfer

Tags: linux, windows, character-encoding, ftp, codepages

We have two machines (unix and windows) and we send a file vía FTP from first (unix [IBM1047]) to second (windows [UTF16]). If you use ASCII mode, some especial characters such as Ñ ó... are not display correctly. So we changed to BINARY mode and after the transfer we set charset file to UTF16. But everything works fine except returns carriages which are not displayed (1 line un the file).

So what is we missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary mode means that there are no changes done to the file, which includes changes on the line endings. UNIX and Windows have traditionally different line endings, i.e. \n on UNIX vs. \r\n on Windows. If your application is not able to deal with UNIX-style line endings you have to convert all the line endings in the file. See also [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings).