# Bash syntax error

Tags: bash, shell, sh, raspbian, debian-based

Just learning bash and trying to implement a function in a script.

The script below runs thru ShellCheck fine, but I get a syntax error running bash from the command line

It must be the way I've defined my function, but I can't figure out the right way to do it - especially if it passes ShellCheck

```
error is on line 24
syntax error near unexpected token `${\r''
`autounload() {
```

> **Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# /home/pi/scripts/usb-unloader.sh
#
# Called from {SCRIPT_DIR}/usb-initloader.sh
# make sure to chmod 0755 on file
#
# UnMounts usb device on /media/<device>
# Logs changes to /var/log/syslog and local log folder
# use tail /var/log/syslog to look at latest events in log
#
# CONFIGURATION
#
LOG_FILE="$1"
MOUNT_DIR="$2"
DEVICE="$3"  # USB device name (from kernel parameter passed from rule)
#
# check for defined log file
if [ -z "$LOG_FILE" ]; then
    exit 1
fi
#
# autounload function to unmount USB device and remove mount folder
#
autounload() {
    if [ -z "$MOUNT_DIR" ]; then
        exit 1
    fi
    if [ -z "$DEVICE" ]; then
        exit 1
    fi

    dt=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    echo "--- USB Auto UnLoader --- $dt"

    sudo umount "/dev/$DEVICE"
    sudo rmdir "$MOUNT_DIR/$DEVICE"

    # test that this device isn't already mounted
    device_mounted=$(grep "$DEVICE" /etc/mtab)

    if ! "$device_mounted"; then
        echo "/dev/$DEVICE successfully Un-Mounted"
        exit 1
    fi
}

autounload >> "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1
```

This is the part of the code where I start defining the function

```
#
autounload() {
    if [ -z "$MOUNT_DIR" ]; then
        exit 1
    fi
```

I've tried to move function above and below where it gets called but it seems to makes no difference.

Comment: you probably have a DOS file running in UNIX. Try to run `dos2unix` to "clean" it

Comment: I'm editing on Windows using Textpad then ftp over. So if  I just use sudo nano that should clean it up?

Comment: Not really, since Windows has different line endings. Just use the tool `dos2unix` (or others as seen in [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17579553/1983854)) to replace those.

Comment: Thanks! - Damn - should have asked an hour ago! - Put that in an answer and I'll mark it. This has been a steep learning curve for me.

Comment: Haha nice to read that this was useful. Happy coding!!

Comment: This is covered in the [`bash` tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: Wow - that looks like a great resource - I don't know if I would have found it looking for syntax errors in the toc - but there's a few other great hints I can use already. Next up - trying to find out why my udev rules aren't working any more

Comment: @chepner that is indeed a great resource. I somehow think hardly anybody knows about it, so it makes me think that having good canonical Q&A may be best on the long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discovered in comments, you have a Windows (DOS) file that then runs on a UNIX machine. This has the problem that the line endings in DOS are `\r\n` while in UNIX are `\n`, so there is a superfluous `\r` in every line.

To get rid of those you can use either of these:

- In UNIX: `dos2unix`
- In Windows: any of the tools described in [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17579553/1983854)