# VBE import code module is coming through as the wrong type

Tags: vba

I have downloaded some code modules (.cls files) from a Git Repository.  When I import (some, not all) into the VBE (File: Import), it imports it as a 'Standard' module (as if it were a .bas file).

If I open the cls file in Notepad++, copy the entire contents to a new file and save as "a.cls" then I can import and it correctly is interpreted as a new Class.

I am totally confused and with lots of code modules to go through, I don't want to have to manually re-save each one.

Does anyone have any ideas?

---

### EDIT

I am importing in to Excel 2016 (64-bit) on Windows 10.  I don't know the Excel version that the files were created in.

The files are at: https://github.com/ckuhn203/VBEX/tree/master/src

As an example: Monadic.cls imports as a standard module file.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the question the version of the application you are importing to and the version of the application that the class files were generated from?

Comment: Is the link to the .cls file public? If not, can you edit the question to include the header (everything through the last `Attribute`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the files have a single `LF` for the line break.

MS Office expects code files to use `CRLF`. Because it doesn't find it, it fails to read the attributes that declare the file is a class.

See e.g. [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17579553/11683) to mass-replace the line breaks.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you very, very much.