# git merge conflict carriage return

Tags: git, merge

If I merge to branches with `git merge branchname` I get a merge conflict, as the new files adds carriage returns (^M) after every line.
I use vim to resolve the conflicts and found out that the `fileformat` of LOCAL, BASE and REMOTE file is `dos` whereas the new file is `unix`.

How do I (permanently) fix such problems? I could remove all the carriage returns by hand, but I don't think this is the right way. I also tried changing the `fileformat` with `set ff` but it didn't change anything.

---

Edit:
[is it possible for git merge to ignore line ending differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861995/is-it-possible-for-git-merge-to-ignore-line-ending-differences) doesn't really help here. The branches I am merging use the same line ending. Only the merge introduces a new line ending. The proposed solutions don't affect my problem, I have tried them before.

Comment: open with a editor that respects the file type and different enter characters

Comment: possible answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings but permanently use editors that do not change line endings and choose a standard (e.g always use unix line endings or always use dos line endings)

Comment: The answer gives a workaround, temporarily I fix the problem by substituting the line ending anyway.
I am using `Vim` as text editor, I thought it already respects line endings, I think there is nothing to do concerning this point.