# How to find & replace regular expressions from a text file?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a huge .txt file in which i want to find the regular expression **(^.+$)\n**   and replace it with **\1\n**. Currently i'm doing it manually.

how can i automate this using batch script?

Comment: sed is your friend for doing batch editing: [man page for sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

Comment: there is no `batch` command for that. But dbenham has written a hybrid batch file to do that (if you can't /don't want to install some unix tools). Search for [jrepl](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jrepl) to find a lot of answers using this tool.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your expression properly:

```
^  - Start of Line.
.+ - Any character, possibly repeated
$  - End of Line
\n - Followed by a blank line
```

And you want to replace it with:

```
Everything you Captured
\n
```

That looks like it does not accomplish anything.
Doesn't that just replace each line with the same line?

Can you clarify your intent?

Comment: I just want to add \r\n at the end of every line.

Comment: Why didn't you say so?   That is a ***very*** different question.  I think what you want is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings