# Batch converting simple text files to .txt windows notepad files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, notepad

I've got many txt files and I want to batch convert them to the standard notepad .txt format from command prompt or batch file

I thought to use `type file.txt > newfile.txt` but the `type` command is not working so I thought to use the `more` command but it limits the output...

EDIT: After looking around, this syntax is working:

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims=, " %i in (TEST.txt) do @echo %i %j %k >> Newfile.txt
```

The problem is that it doesn't write blank lines, so the final total number of lines won't match... and I need to overwrite the original TEST.txt with the output...

Comment: `.txt` to standard notepad `.txt` format. Could you explain what the difference is?

Comment: I'm doing this because the txt files I'm managine if opened by notepad shows all content on the same line, if converted with more command shows correctly on multiple lines...

Comment: Thanks for reply. Seems like the text files maybe ending lines with `LF` instead of `CRLF`.

Comment: Is there a way to fix these files with a batch script?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings)

Comment: Notepad breaks on LF and ignores CR. Wordpad etc break on CR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you may have a file created Unix-like with `LF` line endings instead of the Windows-like `CRLF` line endings. If my assumption is correct you could try using this:

```dos
TYPE "file.txt" | FIND /V "" > "newfile.txt"
```

*`Type` can read `LF` line endings and `Find` effectively converts them to `CRLF`.*

Comment: With `aLFbLF`, I get output of `??CRLF`. `LF` and `CRLF` represent end of lines. I am on Win7. Although I am testing in a loop. May test more.

Comment: Same results with single line. Tried findstr as well but complains `FINDSTR: No search strings` with or without `/L` literal option.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced success with [unix2dos](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/).

```
@echo off

for %%A in (*.txt) do (
    unix2dos "%%~A"
)
```

Default action for unix2dos is overwrite original file.

I advise checking that the target files have same encoding, with BOM or no BOM etc. before mass conversion.