# How to see the line terminator ona .txt on a bare windows7 installation

Tags: mysql, windows, notepad

Basically i'm going to take an exam in mysql next week in which i will have to import some txt files in my editor and launch some query on it.
My problem is that my professor randomly changes '\n' with '\r\n' and i don't know how can i notice it before importing.
Is there any way to do it in a minimal windows 7 machine with only Mysql query browser as editor and windows notepad?

Thanks!

i tried by importing it both in query browser, both in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

I have a file `/tmp/win.txt` in which I saved:

```
Hello\r\n
World\r\n
```

Then I used MySQL to load the file and check if it contains `\r\n` characters:

```
mysql> select instr(load_file('/tmp/win.txt'), '\r\n');
+------------------------------------------+
| instr(load_file('/tmp/win.txt'), '\r\n') |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                        6 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Note this depends on having your MySQL configured with the option `secure_file_priv=/tmp`, or else you can't use [LOAD_FILE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file).

But if I were working on this task, I would just make sure the text file was in UNIX format, so I don't have to test every file with MySQL. See [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings)