how to Check if the code uses \r or \r\n and change it to the other
Have seen this answer that is relevant to me:

Maybe editor and debugger are not using the same interpretation of "newline". Check if the code uses \r or \r\n and change it to the other.

I cannot comment but need to ask... how? I was also told if I need to ask how/why on another question I should make a new question instead:
"Even if you had the reputation to do so [comment], follow up questions should not be asked in the comments. Ask a new question stackoverflow.com/questions/ask and in it, link back to this one for reference."
googling how to do this doesn't really give anything useful

The code uses \n.  Your platform may use \r or \r\n. (Some platforms use NL (\x15, EBCDIC), NEL (\x85, ECMA-94), NU (\0), RS (\x1E, QNX (pre-POSIX)), NEWLINE (\x76, ZX80 & ZX81), US (\x1F, Pick/BASIC)).

You need to explain what actual problem you are trying to solve. It is usual for text files in Linux to use just \n, and Windows to use \r\n. But those are conventions rather than rules. And in both cases most editors and compilers can handle either.

If the file is not following the convention of the operating system, it is not a valid text file. In C++ source, the newline is always '\n' which is then converted when reading/writing to however a text file works. There is nothing to detect.

@BoP That’s kind of like sticking your hands over your ears and yelling LA-LA-LA-LA-LA! — In todays modern internet age, it is absolutely common to have to deal with text files with EOL conventions from other OSes, and the vast majority of modern text editors and tools understand the bare minimum of LF and CRLF.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings

'\n' is typical for unix/linux "\r\n" for windows and "\n\r" for mac. As long as the file is opened as text, target system decides the line ending. For accurate control, the file must be opened as binary; then everything is written bit by bit as user code demands.

You shouldn't need to detect the current form of the file, it doesn't matter that much - you just want to convert ALL the line endings to the form required by your tools.  Open the file in binary mode and start reading.  Ignore all the \r bytes and convert the \n bytes to whichever form you need, either \n or \r\n.  Write to a new file.
